# show php search results in web submission form

Tags: php, forms

I have a web form that can add work ticket information to a database. I need to search now for that information but I need the results to appear in the fields of the submit form. The user must be able to update one or more of those "result" fields before submitting the form a second time to update the database. I can't add a bunch of stuff to the server (like AJAX). Is this even possible? Thanks.

```
<html>

<body>

<div id="naming" class="name-form">

<h3>Add name and click Submit.</h3>

    <form action="search3.php" method="POST">

        <fieldset>
            <label for="name">Name:</label> 
            <input type="text" name="name" size="20" /><br />
            <label for="id_number">ID Number:</label>
            <input type="text" name="id_number" size="20" /><br />
        </fieldset>

    <br/>

        <fieldset class="center">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </fieldset>

    </form>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

The two scripts are in different files.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","names");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$name = trim($_REQUEST['name']);

$id_number = trim($_REQUEST['id_number']);

$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO names (name, id_number) VALUES ('{$name}', '{$id_number}')";

// Add name to database
mysqli_query($con, $insert_sql)
  or die(mysql_error());

?>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=".5; url=http://localhost/testforms/search3.html">
```

Comment: Can you show the simplified code of the form?

Comment: The code is included now - took me longer than I care to admit to figure out how to add them correctly.

Comment: Can you clarify something? Do you want the page to refresh and display field data that was saved in the DB, or do you want the page to automatically populate as the user types in data

Comment: A refresh (after clicking a "search" button) that displays the field data is all that is needed.

Comment: Let me get this straight: you want the user to (1) input something to search, (2) server displays a submit form with search results already in the fields (3) user checks over the data (4) user submits form

Comment: 1) user enters data into a form and submits it to the database with the click of a button 2) to retrieve the data, the user fills in one of the fields of the form and clicks a search button 3) the results of the search appear in the fields of that form

Comment: Please be clearer on the difference between your (1) and (2)

Comment: 1) is just a user filling out a form and getting it added to the database. As for 2), the form is being used to search for information in the database. But where are the results shown? In the fields of the form. I find it hard to describe, honestly...

Answer (score 2):

To do so you need to use `AJAX` and send data with it, receive response and update form input values.

**HTML**

Here we add function which listens to "onclick" event and sends data to "search3.php"

```
<form action="search3.php" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Name:</label> 
        <input class='formElements' type="text" name="name" size="20" /><br />
        <label for="id_number">ID Number:</label>
        <input class='formElements' type="text" name="id_number" size="20" /><br />
    </fieldset>
    <br/>
    <fieldset class="center">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick='sendData(); return false;'/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

This is AJAX function which gets form element values, sends them to server and receives response data in JSON format. Response data is inserted into form element values.

```
function sendData()
{
    var formElements = document.querySelectorAll(".formElement");
    var formData = new FormData(); 
    for(var i = 0; i < formElements.length; i++)
        formData.append(formElements[i].name, formElements[i].value);
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200)
            {
                var responseText = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
                formElements[0].value = responseText[0];
                formElements[1].value = responseText[1];
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.open("POST", "search3.php"); 
        xmlHttp.send(formData);
}
```

**PHP**

Here you get form element values from AJAX function.
After that you insert it into database, get `last insert id` to select newly inputted data and return it to client in JSON format.

```
<?php 
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $id = $_POST["id_number"];

    $con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "names");

    $prepare = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `names` (`name`, `id_number`) VALUES (?, ?); 
        $prepare->bind_param("ss", $name, $id); 
        $prepare->execute();
        $prepare->close();
     $lastInsertId = $con->insert_id;

    $prepareTwo = $con->prepare("SELECT `name`, `id_number` FROM `names` where `id` = ?); 
        $prepareTwo->bind_param("s", $lastInsertId);
        $prepareTwo->execute();
        $prepareTwo->store_result();
        $prepareTwo->bind_result($name, $id_number);
        $prepareTwo->fetch();
        $prepareTwo->close();

    $con->close();

        $responseArray = array();
        $responseArray[0] = $name;
        $responseArray[1] = $id_number;

        $responseArray = json_encode($responseArray);
        echo $responseArray;
?>
```

Comment: It sounds like this will retrieve only the latest entry but we need to search against all existing records. I'm not sure about the AJAX stuff either but if I understand it correctly, I could enclose JS in "script" tags in the HTML file, right? It will take me some time to go through this and understand the flow but thank you for response. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I get the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'ss' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp64\www\testforms\search3-1.php on line 8. This is how I used the above answer. I added the JS to the HTML file uses "script" tags and pointed that to the PHP in a new file called search3-1.php but I get the above error.